# How to create an insert trigger on Azure CosmosDB using MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I would like to implement [this solution](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb#use-a-single-counter-document-to-generate-unique-identifiers-one-at-a-time) from Mongodb Inc using a CosmosDB trigger, but I don't know if triggers using the MongoDB API are possible, and if they are, I can't seem to find any examples. Here's a simple working javascript that implements that solution on the client side:

```
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){

   var sequenceDocument = db.counters.findAndModify({
      query:{_id: sequenceName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
      new:true
   });

   return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
}

db.products.insert({
   "_id":getNextSequenceValue("productid"),
   "product_name":"Apple iPhone",
   "category":"mobiles"
})
```

Would it be possible to do this server side using a CosmosDB trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never and maybe someone will come across.

Azure Cosmos DB supports only triggers, UDF and stored procedure for the CORE (SQL) API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function

> Azure Cosmos DB bindings are only supported for use with the SQL API.
> For all other Azure Cosmos DB APIs, you should access the database
> from your function by using the static client for your API, including
> Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB, Cassandra API, Gremlin API, and
> Table API.